# django AdminSplitDateTime valid date/time error

Tags: python, django, date

i'm using AdminSplitDateTime in a model form that i use as a form_class in a CreateView.

when i used this in windows with django version 1.8.3 with runserver

i could save dates in the format: yyyy-mm-dd (2015-12-17) hh:mm:ss (09:22:24)

when i moved my project to ubuntu and upgraded my django to 1.9 and ran

it with gunicorn and nginx it error "Enter a valid date/time."

but when i saved it in the admin page with DateTimeField it ran just fine.

does anyone know why it had problems when i tried to save it with the form?

Answer (score 15):

Though you probably solved this on your own in the past 3 months I stumbled upon your question while dealing with a similar issue.

The behavior of this widget has changed in Django 1.9, as mentioned in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9):

> The ability to use a SplitDateTimeWidget with DateTimeField is
> removed.

SplitDateTimeWidget now requires `django.form.SplitDateTimeField` instead of `django.forms.DateTimefield`. Same applies for the `AdminSplitDateTime` from `django.contrib.admin.widgets`, obviously.

**Example**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    mydatetime = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime())
```

Comment: From the Django 1.7 release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.7/#splitdatetimewidget-with-datetimefield